# How to prevent bootstrap from "drop" at mobile screen size?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

For example, I have this

```css
        .form-group select {
            display: inline;
        }
```

```html
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group form-inline">
            <input class="form-control" type="number" name="currency_from_amount" id="currency_from_amount">
            <select class="form-control" name="currency_from_code" id="currency_from_code"></select>
        </div>        
    </div>
```

When the screen become smaller, the dropdownlist "drop" into another row which is not what I want. How do I maintain to make it inline (two columns in one row) even it is mobile size?

Expected output is:
[image]

But current output is
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for your expected output. You need to wrap the `input and select box` in a `row` by specifying the `col` size as per your requirement.

```css
.container {
  padding: 10px;
}
.nopadding {
   padding: 0 !important;
   margin: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
        <input class="form-control " type="number" name="currency_from_amount" id="currency_from_amount">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-2 nopadding">
        <select class="form-control" name="currency_from_code" id="currency_from_code"></select>
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
        <input class="form-control " type="number" name="currency_from_amount" id="currency_from_amount">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-2 nopadding">
        <select class="form-control" name="currency_from_code" id="currency_from_code"></select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```